# Push permission denied when has mix contributor commits

Tags: github, terminal

I have a local git repo with commits from two different accounts. One of the two accounts does not has permission to a remote github repo which I want to push to.

An error occurs when pushing. How can I fix this without copying the whole code to another place and `git init` from begin to make it under one single contributor because I want to keep the commits history.

Can I just somehow force to overwrite some commits to make them disappear? In order to push the local code with one permitted account.

Comment: What error occurs when pushing? When it prompts for a username and password, which username did you supply?

Comment: it just saying, permission denied to xxx(username),

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out this issue. Permission has nothing to do with the commits authors. It is for the github account I was logged in when I was trying to push.

I googled many times about how to switch account via terminal on Mac, something like "git config command line" does not work.

The easiest way is to go to keychain access, search "git", delete the denied one. Then when you pushing, terminal will ask you for uesrname and password.